# CodeDeploy onpremise registration failing with AccessDeniedException on Amazon Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, amazon-lightsail

aws deploy register-on-premises-instance --instance-name XXXXX --iam-user-arn arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/LightSailCodeDeployUser --region ap-south-1

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the RegisterOnPremisesInstance operation: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/AmazonLightsailInstanceRole/i-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX is not authorized to perform: codedeploy:RegisterOnPremisesInstance on resource: arn:aws:codedeploy:ap-south-1:XXXXXXXXXX:instance:XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I didn't even create the role AmazonLightsailInstanceRole, then how did it come in the picture. My user have all permissions on codedeploy though. I am following this link to set up. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-codedeploy-and-aws-codepipeline-to-deploy-applications-to-amazon-lightsail/

Comment: Can you let me know what's the issue with the code. I have removed that " after --instance-name

Answer (score 3):

I made the same mistake and then realized that command is meant to be run on your **local machine**  and not the instance!

Comment: the documentation I'm reading says the same. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 2):

`AmazonLightsailInstanceRole` is a [service-linked role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/using-service-linked-roles.html) automatically created by aws:

> Service-linked roles are **predefined** by the service and include all the permissions that the service requires to call other AWS services on your behalf.

The error you are getting is not about you not having the `codedeploy:RegisterOnPremisesInstance` permission.

The error is about the `AmazonLightsailInstanceRole` not having it. It does not matter if you (i.e. your IAM user) has all `CodeDeploy` permissions.

Normally you would add the missing permissions to the role. How to work with the `AmazonLightsailInstanceRole` is described in the following AWS documentaiton:

- [Using Service-Linked Roles for Amazon Lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-service-linked-roles)
- [Editing a Service-Linked Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/using-service-linked-roles.html#edit-service-linked-role)

However, I'm not sure if you can modify the `AmazonLightsailInstanceRole` and add the missing permissions. Some service-linked roles can be modified, some not.

Comment: Did you find if you can edit `AmazonLightsailInstanceRole` or add a specific IAM policy to Lightsail instance ?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is a bit confusing. Create a new user in IAM with admin role (full privileges) and use the credentials of that user to run the command in your local machine.

Comment: This is the easiest method. Not sure about security though